# NFS host is not exporting the "share"

Tags: linux, redhat, mount, nfs

I have a NFS Server: `usanfsd01` And a remote machine: `usafssd01`

I tried mounting a directory from `usafssd01` onto `usanfsd01` by adding the following line to `/etc/fstab` as root

```
usanfsdo1:/home/dblogs /home/data/dblogs  nfs    rw  0  0
```

And when I run the following command to see if NFS is exporting the share, it's not shown

```
showmount -e usanfsdo1
```

Can someone please help? Also, a point of interest would be there is another mount that works on the same servers and thats defined as below in the `/etc/fstab`

```
usanfsdo1:/home/files /home/data/files  nfs    rw  0  0
```

**/etc/exports**

```
/nfs/home/dblogs 'IPADDRESS'(rw,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: Log file entries? Is this directory listed in `/etc/exports` on `usanfsd01`? What happens if you try to mount manually with `mount`?

Comment: I don't know where to see the log file entries.

Comment: the directory is listed in /etc/exports on the usanfsd01. I haven't tried to mount manually yet

Comment: Did you reboot after adding the entries to `/etc/fstab`? Mounts in there will only be activated during boot, not automatically after adding the line. Try `mount -a` to mount everything in `fstab` without a reboot.

Comment: Okay. when I ran mount -a it threw me an error as below,
mount.nfs: Access denied by server while mounting usanfsdo1:/home/files

Answer (score 1):

I assume the spelling mistake is just here, and not in `/etc/fstab`, but I will point it out anyway. You say the servername is `usanfsd01`, but in `/etc/fstab` you have added `usanfsdo1`. The letter 'O' vs. the number '0'.

Since you are exporting `/nfs/home/dblogs` you need to changed your entry in `/etc/fstab` to something like this:

```
usanfsdo1:/nfs/home/dblogs /home/data/dblogs  nfs    rw  0  0
```

Make sure this is correct, and then run the following command to mount the NFS-directory

```
# mount -a
```

or

```
$ sudo mount -a
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo here. I cross checked on /etc/fstab. Okay. when I ran mount -a it threw me an error as below, mount.nfs: Access denied by server while mounting usanfsdo1:/home/files

Comment: Can you post the content of `/etc/export` on the server here? So I can update the answer.

Comment: /nfs/home/dblogs 'IPADDRESS'(rw,no_root_squash)

Comment: Okay, updated the answer with an `fstab`-entry.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the NFS server processes and rpcbind are running on the remote server.

Red Hat:

```
chkconfig rpcbind on
chkconfig nfs on
service rpcbind start
service nfs start
```

SuSE:

```
chkconfig rpcbind on
chkconfig nfsserver on
service rpcbind start
service nfs start
```

Then, on the server confirm that you're actually exporting those filesystems:

```
showmount -e
```

Good luck.